# Highlight Selected Image Area and Action - Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, image-processing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Need to load the image from resource path and then area should be selected and have to add some comments against selected area.

How to achieve in Xamarin Forms(Android and iOS)?

Comment: I always want my solutions to be adorable...

Comment: you need to provide a better explanation of what you're trying to do.  Perhaps add some mockups of what you are trying to accomplish.  Generally speaking, if you want to layer shapes and text on top of a bitmap, use SkiaSharp

Comment: Example: I have shown an animal image in Xamarin forms UI. I need to mention parts of that animal after selected a specific area (like nose, eye, legs ).

Comment: are the paths for each body part pre-defined?  Or do you expect to determine that programatically?

Comment: determine that programmatically.

Comment: If you don't have a specific definition, I'm afraid you can't recognize what you're clicking on.